# How to write LabelEncoder in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to parse directories on Google Storage into strings, but I keep getting errors. I want to find the directory of each file and return a numerical encoding of the directory name as a Dataset. This would be trivial in sklearn using LabelEncoder, but I'm having trouble doing this in Tensorflow.

```
CLASS_NAMES = [b'class_1', b'class_2', b'class_3']
labeler = tfds.features.ClassLabel(names=CLASS_NAMES)

def parse_filenames(filename):
    label = tf.strings.split(tf.expand_dims(filename, axis=-1), sep='/')
    label = label.values[-2]

    # Problem is in the two lines below
    position_feature = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list('label_names', CLASS_NAMES)
    label = tf.io.parse_example(label, features=position_feature)

    return label

folder = b'gs://<bucket>/train/*/*.jpg'
filenames_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(folder)
label_dataset = filenames_dataset.map(parse_filenames)

next(iter(label_dataset))
```

I get an error `ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 16; 2 is required`

If I take out the two lines under the "# Problem is here" comment, it works fine, except it returns a string instead of an integer. I've tried other non-tensorflow options, such as <list_name>.index(label), but those of course fail because everything is a tensor instead of a string. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try this line instead of these two lines:

```
label = tf.argmax(tf.cast(parts[-2] == CLASS_NAMES, tf.int32))
```

You will get something like `[0, 1, 0]` (the index of the label in `CLASS_NAMES`).

Functioning and reproducible example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from string import ascii_lowercase as letters

CLASS_NAMES = [b'class_1', b'class_2', b'class_3']

files = ['\\'.join([np.random.choice(CLASS_NAMES).decode(),
                    ''.join(np.random.choice(list(letters), 5)) + '.jpg']) 
         for i in range(10)]

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(files)
```

Here are the fake files I generated:

```
['class_3\\jrxog.jpg',
 'class_1\\slfiq.jpg',
 'class_2\\svldd.jpg',
 'class_2\\avrgt.jpg',
 'class_3\\wqwuv.jpg']
```

Now implement this:

```
def get_label(file_path):
    parts = tf.strings.split(file_path, '\\')
    return file_path, tf.argmax(tf.cast(parts[-2] == CLASS_NAMES, tf.int32))

ds = ds.map(get_label)

next(iter(ds))
```

```
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'class_1\\bbqrx.jpg'>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=0>)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This produces one-hot-encoding. I'm trying to encode as a single int, so class_1 -> 0, class_2 -> 1, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I changed it.

Comment: you can just remove the `file_path` in the return statement, it's just for demonstration

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

i used the label encoder from sklearn. This is something that you may have to pickle, that way you can reverse transform your outcome later on. Im still new at this so im not sure how well this might work for you