# Deep learning model : ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'php'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to make a deep learning to predict the tag (c, php, ...) of stack overflow posts. However, when I try to fit my model, I had a lot of errors about the shape of my training set. After correcting these, I receive a new error and I don't know how to correct it. If you could help me correct it because i'm new with deep learning models, it will be really nice from you !

My code :

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(16,activation='relu',input_shape = (384,))) #hidden
model.add(Dense(len(data.tag_name.unique()),activation='sigmoid')) #output

model.compile(optimizer='SGD',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(np.array(list_embedding),tf.one_hot(np.array(data.tag_name).reshape([2686,1]),depth=len(data.tag_name.unique())),validation_data=0.3,epochs=20)
```

X_train : [X_train](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTpm5.png)
y_train : [y_train](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nK7I7.png)

The error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-3fddbbfa9112> in <module>
     10 
     11 model.compile(optimizer='SGD',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
---> 12 model.fit(np.array(list_embedding),tf.one_hot(np.array(data.tag_name).reshape([2686,1]),depth=len(data.tag_name.unique())),validation_data=0.3,epochs=20) #reshape y one hot encoding dummies

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    204     """Call target, and fall back on dispatchers if there is a TypeError."""
    205     try:
--> 206       return target(*args, **kwargs)
    207     except (TypeError, ValueError):
    208       # Note: convert_to_eager_tensor currently raises a ValueError, not a

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py in one_hot(indices, depth, on_value, off_value, axis, dtype, name)
   4347                       "dtype {1} of off_value".format(on_dtype, off_dtype))
   4348 
-> 4349     return gen_array_ops.one_hot(indices, depth, on_value, off_value, axis,
   4350                                  name)
   4351 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py in one_hot(indices, depth, on_value, off_value, axis, name)
   6232   if tld.is_eager:
   6233     try:
-> 6234       _result = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_FastPathExecute(
   6235         _ctx, "OneHot", name, indices, depth, on_value, off_value, "axis",
   6236         axis)

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'php'
```

Comment: You need to transform/encode these strings (labels) to/as integers or apply one hot encoding.

Comment: `neural network` can work only with numbers so you have to convert strings `c, php, etc.` to numbers. And when you get result (also number) then you have convert this number to one of the strings `c, php, etc.`

Comment: But, the tf.one_hot is supposed to convert the strings as integers no ?

Answer (score 0):

Encode the labels using LabelEncoder

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
labelencode = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

labelencode.fit(["php", "c#", "c++", "python"])

y_train = labelencode.transform(["python", "php", "python"])
```

**Output**

```
array([3, 2, 3])
```

Also take a look at similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/62760616/14290244